# Dell Inspiron laptop not starting

Tags: boot, laptop, power-supply, battery, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron N5010 dual booting Windows 7 and Ubuntu. It was running fine earlier, but suddenly it started mistyping letters with multiple letters and special characters for one second and then it shuts down.

After that the laptop was not starting for a while. A few hours later it again started (with Ubuntu) and did the same once I pressed any key on keyboard, but now the laptop is not starting at all. The power LED goes on for one second and then shuts off without starting the fan or booting till BIOS. The same cycle of on and off without anything on screen or beep sound is repeating.

Initially while misprints were happening, I checked all the keys in the keyboard, pressing NumLock and combinations of NumLock and other keys. After that I tried discharging static charge by pressing the power button for a while without any power connection.

I disassembled the laptop to clean the fan and check for any burns inside, but everything is fine. I reassembled it, but it's still the same.

I tried starting the laptop without battery with power supply / with battery without power supply / with both. Nothing is working.

I tried without hdd with and without battery still same.

I removed the 2 ram chip and then started it , now the fan is getting started and producing 2 beep sound, but the system is not shutting down.

Comment: What happens if remove hdd? battery and hdd?

Comment: still behaving the same without hdd and battery

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qcWowCgOFOw and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KVHu51Fe1e4

Comment: It could be a broken RAM stick, easy to repair by replacing the broken RAM stick. Take your laptop to a computer repair technician and tell him to check the laptop with a new RAM stick. Checking the RAM should only take a few minutes.

Comment: well i removed one ram and tried starting with only one ram, it started with windows recovery.
 it deleted lot of files giving [error](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/169404) 
after that i tried adding the other ram also and its working perfectly fine.
But iam not getting what is /was the problem?